# First name and last name validation in Yii

Tags: php, validation, yii

I have been using Yii for some time.

Here is my question.
Say I have an inquiry form.
The form has to have first name field and last name field.

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'first_name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'last_name'); ?>
```

But I want to show only one error message for both field with message like (Both first name and last name are required)
I do not want two different error messages like the following

```
<?php echo $form->error($model,'first_name'); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'last_name'); ?>
```

How can I do that?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make custom validation in model:

```
public function rules()
    {
    return array(
        array('first_name,last_name', 'my_required'),
....
}
public function my_required()
    {
if (!isset($this->first_name)||!isset($this->last_name)||$this->first_name==''||$this->last_name=='')
       $this->addError('first_name','Please provide first name and last name');//add to atribute where you want to display error
    }
```

Also you can do it with hasError($attribute) function. So check your fname, lname for errors and show your error manually.